# Select elements of child tables with a given property

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am really not good at sql, The problem is the following: 
I have a metadata table like this

```
META:
id(pk)  prop1   prop2
     1  'pr1'   'pr2'
     2  'pr1'   'pr2'
```

At the same time, I have many child tables which look something like this:

```
TABLE1:
metaID(fk-pk)   indx(pk)    active  ...
            1          1         1  ...
            1          2         0  ...
            1          3         1  ...
            2          1         1  ...
```

and a second table similar to the first

```
TABLE2:
metaID(fk-pk)   indx(pk)    active  ...
            1          1         1  ...
            1          2         1  ...
            2          1         0  ...
            2          2         0  ...
```

I need a query which retrieves the the metadata table properties and the number of records in each child table which are active.

For example if I want the elements with `prop1 = 'pr1` the query should answer:

```
meta-id prop1   prop2   TAB1CNT TAB2CNT
      1 'pr1'   'pr2'         2       2
      2 'pr1'   'pr2'         1       0
```

where `TAB1CNT` is the count of the active elements of `TABLE1` and the same goes for `TAB2CNT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. This would return all meta records, regardless of if there were any active records in table1 or table2.

```
SELECT ID, prop1, prop2, ISNULL(t1.ActiveCount, 0) AS TAB1CNT, ISNULL(t2.ActiveCount, 0) AS TAB2CNT
FROM META m
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT metaID, COUNT(*) AS ActiveCount
        FROM TABLE1
        WHERE active = 1
        GROUP BY metaID
    ) t1 ON m.ID = t1.metaID
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT metaID, COUNT(*) AS ActiveCount
        FROM TABLE2
        WHERE active = 1
        GROUP BY metaID
    ) t2 ON m.ID = t2.metaID
```

Hopefully from this, you can then add whatever clauses you want to return only the META records you are interested in.